# HTML child wider than parent container

Tags: html, css

There is an outer div, and an inner div element. Sometimes I see that the inner div is wider than the outer div.

When does this happen? And how to overcome this issue?

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this can have many many reasons... please narrow your issue down.

Comment: I dont remember exactly what the css was. but am sure there was no overflow property to either elements. but there was padding, margin that was causing the issue...!

Comment: use `box-sizing:border-box` which will give padding from inside or it will be `width` + `padding`  100% width + xxpx padding

Answer (score 6):

According to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191430/html-child-wider-than-parent-container/26191507#comment41069090_26191430) the reason the inner element is wider than parent is caused by the margin/padding. This happens when you set

```
(width + padding + margin + border) of child > parent width
```

[**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/s564p2sc/)

**Workarounds :**

- **For margin :** You need to calculate `(width + margin) of child =< parent width` **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/s564p2sc/2/)**
- **For border and padding :** You can use the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property to include padding and border in the width of the element  **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/s564p2sc/1/)** *(or use the same technique as margin)*
- **For border, margin and padding :** When you don't need to set a width on the inner element, remove it and the default behaviour for block elements will include margin, padding and border inside the parent **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/s564p2sc/3/)**

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">Inner Text</div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
  #inner,  #outer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    padding: 1%;
  }
</style>
```